# How to remove the searching PID from this command line?

Tags: unix, command-line

I've written a little script to find the IDs of the processes I'm interested in running `kill -9` on.  It reads something like this:

`ps -A -o pid -o command | egrep 'java' | cut -d' ' -f1`

However, I also get the PID for the command that runs the `egrep java`.  I'd like to alter my above command that looks for 'java' to exclude the one that is the `egrep java`.

I'm fairly new to the command line and I'm not really sure how to do that.

Comment: Does your system have the `pgrep` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
ps -A -o pid -o command | egrep '[f]lash' | cut -d' ' -f1
```

**(OR)**

If you have `pgrep` command,

```
pgrep 'java'
```

It will give you the pid.